# C - Segmentation fault in a string to morse code program

Tags: c, pointers

I've been trying to code a really simple string to morse code converter in C for a few hours now and I finally got it to compile without any warnings. I'm a beginner in C so I really cannot understand how to fix my code. I believe the problem should be in how I pass strings around with pointers and etc, since this is the part I do not understand the most. I found an example on how to do it, but I still couldn't understand it, and there wasn't any specific case that would be similar to mine, since I want it to read strings from the arguments (all arguments are strings/words).

And now I'm getting a segmentation fault when trying to run it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int to_morse(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char morse[80];
    char *temp;
    for (int counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++)
    {
        *temp = to_morse(argv[counter]);
        strcat(temp, morse);
        printf("%s", morse);
    }

    return 0;
}

int to_morse(char *str)
{
    char *morse[27] =  {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
    char *output;
    char character;

    for (int counter = 0; str[counter] != '\0'; counter++)
    {
        character = toupper(str[counter]);
        strcat(morse[character-'A'], output);
    }

    return *output;
}
```

I believe this is not a correct way to pass around strings using pointers, but I cannot figure out the right way. How would I be able to make my code work?

Note: I'm aware this might have a duplicate somewhere.. however, there are tons of segmentation fault questions and all of them are really specific and do not cover my scenario, so I couldn't find one.

Comment: You can't just `strcat` to a command line argument!

Comment: Please: turn on, read and try to understand the compiler warnings.

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani You're right that I tried to fix most of them without understanding them first. However, they're turned on, the code I've posted here got me no warnings.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, sorry, I'm quite new to C, I see that I've understood some things wrong. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Fanatique you're right, by default GCC (if you're using it) does now show the uninitialized variable used. Always compile with a decent warning level, like `gcc -Wall`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is so much going wrong with your code.

Firstly, `strcat` takes 2 parameters - a destination and then a source. In all cases that you're using it, you've got them the wrong way around.

Secondly, your function `to_morse` returns an `int` when you want it to return a `char *`. That would be how you pass around pointers.

Thirdly, you don't allocate any memory for `output` in that function, so even if you had the `strcat` the right way around, you've not got anywhere to store the morse code. That'll also be where the code is crashing as you're passing in an uninitialised pointer to `strcat`.

Finally, you should probably check that the character you're trying to convert to morse is a letter, otherwise you'll go out of bounds on your array.

Here is how your code should look. I've also tweaked it so that you put a space between each morse "letter" as otherwise you'd not be able to tell where one begins and another ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *to_morse(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *temp;
    for (int counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++)
    {
        temp = to_morse(argv[counter]);
        printf("%s", temp);
        free(temp); // Always remember to free memory you allocate
    }

    return 0;
}

char *to_morse(char *str)
{
    char *morse[27] =  {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
    char *output=malloc((strlen(str)*5)+1); // Always remember to allocate 1 more char than you need to store the NUL terminate when allocating memory for strings.
    output[0] = '\0'; // strcat need a null terminator in the string.
    char character;

    for (int counter = 0; str[counter] != '\0'; counter++)
    {
        if(isalpha(str[counter]))
        {
            character = toupper(str[counter]);
            strcat(output,morse[character-'A']);
            strcat(output," ");
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: `strcat` needs a null terminator in the string, but you are using it in uninitialized memory.

Comment: Oops! Good call, @GiovanniCerretani

Comment: I don't even know how I haven't noticed that I've used `strcat` the wrong way around. And yeah, I understand now that memory management is something important in C. Thank you for your answer, I understand it perfectly.

Comment: Note: For other [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#Symbol_representations) characters, like `'?'`, `(strlen(str)*6)+1)` needed.